# Missing something in my input for CountryData dependencies

Tags: data, curated-data, list-manipulation

I'm trying to find 
(a)which countries have dependencies 
(b)and a list of countries that consider themselves dependencies 
(c)and a list of countries that don't consider themselves dependencies.

---

Okay, so to find the countries that have dependencies (part a) I input

```
 CountryData["Countries", "Dependencies"]
```

But that output gives me {} throughout the list with the names of 10 or so countries, which I'm not sure are correct.

---

For part b, of finding the countries that consider themselves dependencies, I have:

```
 Flatten[Map[CountyData[#,"Dependencies"]&]]
```

for this part I'm not sure what else I am missing.

---

I got stuck at part b, so I think this part is similar to part c.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The dependencies refer to territories that are not official states of the governing countries, but are also not sovereign states in their own right. It's not clear what you intend to do with the mapping operation, but if I had to guess, you probably wanted to do something like this:

```
Map[{#, CountryData[#, "Dependencies"]} &, CountryData["Countries"]] /. 
    {_, {}} :> Sequence[]
(* {{"Australia", {"ChristmasIsland", "CocosKeelingIslands", "NorfolkIsland"}}, 
    {"China", {"HongKong", "Macau"}}, ... } *)
```

i.e., each country paired with its dependencies.

I prefer using rules for such purposes, so I would've probably written this as:

```
Thread[CountryData["Countries"] -> 
    CountryData["Countries", "Dependencies"]] ~DeleteCases~ Rule[_, {}]
(* {"Australia" -> {"ChristmasIsland", "CocosKeelingIslands", "NorfolkIsland"}, 
    "China" -> {"HongKong", "Macau"}, ... } *)
```

You can also do this the other way round – a rule mapping each dependency to its governing state:

```
Thread /@ Thread[CountryData["Countries", "Dependencies"] -> 
     CountryData["Countries"]] ~DeleteCases~ Rule[{}, _] // Flatten
(* {"ChristmasIsland" -> "Australia", "CocosKeelingIslands" -> "Australia", 
    "NorfolkIsland" -> "Australia", "HongKong" -> "China", "Macau" -> "China", ... *)
```

Comment: I haven't gotten to the point of using the command thread yet, but I'll look out for it.  as for your Map function, what does this mean:     /. {_, {}} :> Sequence[]

Comment: @asik Lookup `ReplaceAll`. In short, it removes sublists of length 2 that have a `{}` as the second element.

Comment: Okay, thanks.  I think it was the Sequence part that threw me off originally.

Comment: Also, is there a way to check out which countries aren't dependencies?  I tried using the != notion since I couldn't think of something that would counter the input for part b.

Comment: @asik Countries aren't dependencies by definition... did you mean to find which countries don't have dependencies?

Comment: Yeah, that's why I meant.  I cannot seem to think of a way.

Comment: @asik The countries without dependencies are exactly those countries that were removed with `/. {_, {}} :> Sequence[]`. Just don't do that and you'll have both lists. If you want to separate out those countries, look up `Cases`.

Comment: Okay, I've looked into using Cases, but I don't see how it relates to separating the countries.  The closest I've come is attempting to use the idea where they use Cases[......,Except[....]]

Comment: @asik Ok, try this: `Select[CountryData["Countries"], 
 CountryData[#, "Dependencies"] == {} &]`. I'll still leave the `Cases` one as an exercise for you :)

Comment: Okay thanks.  I tried a few inputs using Cases, some inputs gave me the same output as if I had not separated them.  And others  just gave me {}.

Answer (score 2):

here's a possible way:

```
With[{cd = CountryData[]}, 
  {#[[All, 1]], Flatten@#[[All, 2]], Complement[cd, Flatten@#[[All, 2]]]} &
  @(Select[#, #[[2]] != {} &] &@({#, CountryData[#, "Dependencies"]} & /@ cd))]
```

Note that it is essentially based on

```
(Select[#, #[[2]] != {} &] &@({#, CountryData[#, "Dependencies"]} & /@ CountryData[]))
```

Which gives a nested list of countries and its dependencies.